Deciding how $X_1$ will influence $Y$ over different time periods?
I am wondering if in regression it is possible to decide how exactly we want a given predictor variable to influence the response variable. For example, consider this basic model (Model 1):
$$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ \frac{\partial y_t}{\partial x_{1t}} = \beta_1 $$
Model 2: I want to make a regression model in which the effect of $X_1$ decreases with time. I thought that I could just do this by adding an exponential decay function?
$$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1(x_{1t} \times e^{-\lambda t}) + \beta_2x_{2t} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ \frac{\partial y_t}{\partial x_{1t}} = \beta_1e^{-\lambda t} $$
Model 3: Or perhaps I want to make a  regression model in which the effect of $X_1$ is small at first, then increases with time, and then again decreases. I thought I could make this as a quadratic function?
$$ y_t = \beta_0 + (\gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2)x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ \frac{\partial y_t}{\partial x_{1t}} = \gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2 $$
I thought I could use MLE to estimate them. E.g. for Model 3:
$$ y_t = \beta_0 + (\gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2)x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ \epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $$
$$ y_t|x_{1t},x_{2t} \sim N(\beta_0 + (\gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2)x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t}, \sigma^2) $$
$$ L_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_t - [\beta_0 + (\gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2)x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t}])^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
$$ L = \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_t - [\beta_0 + (\gamma_1t + \gamma_2t^2)x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t}])^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
Is it statistically correct to make such modifications? Will these modified models have problems with identifiability or other estimation problems?

Why do you want to require certain patterns here, rather than, say, running a spline regression and seeing what the data say?

Good point. Some of the variables represent concepts like immunity to a disease after taking a medication. I figured that this slowly increases and reaches a threshold. This is why I wanted to a priori model it as exponential decay for instance.
